# Typescript array asignment error

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have this class:

**user.ts**

```
const ADMIN = 1;
const AGENT = 2;
const ADJUSTER = 3;
const MANAGER = 4;
const MOTORCYCLIST = 5;

export class User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  status: string;
  role: number;

  isAdmin(): boolean {
    return this.role === ADMIN;
  }

  isAgent(): boolean {
    return this.role === AGENT;
  }

  isAdjuster(): boolean {
    return this.role === ADJUSTER;
  }

  isManager(): boolean {
    return this.role === MANAGER;
  }

  isMotorcyclist(): boolean {
    return this.role === MOTORCYCLIST;
  }
}
```

For testing reasons I'm using a mock users array (for brevity I will show an array of just 5 users, but in my code I have more than 1000):

**mock-users.ts**

```
import { User } from '../models/user';

export const USERS: User[] = [{"id":301,"name":"Shirlee Zboncak","email":"kenyatta_jerde@erdman.ca","phone":"044 93 1342 0977","status":"inactive","role":3},{"id":302,"name":"Erich Auer","email":"grazyna.romaguera@bogisich.name","phone":"044 87 8444 6879","status":"inactive","role":2},{"id":303,"name":"Jerrold McDermott","email":"lindsey_brekke@beierdickinson.info","phone":"044 64 7490 1751","status":"inactive","role":3},{"id":304,"name":"Yael Hilpert","email":"stanton.abbott@pouros.co.uk","phone":"044 16 9190 7970","status":"inactive","role":4},{"id":305,"name":"Pat Hodkiewicz","email":"elin@sanford.biz","phone":"044 12 0242 7692","status":"inactive","role":3}]
```

The problem is that that code fails with [this message in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzqgt.png)

And in my editor it shows this another message:

```
Missing property 'isAdmin' on type '{ "id": number; "name": string; "email": string; "phone": string; "status": string; "role": numbe...'.
```

How can I make my User class to not try to assign the methods. I only want to assign those id, name, email, phone, status and role properties. I have tried to use a constructor but the error is the same.

Comment: “I have tried to use a constructor but the error is the same.” I doubt this; please show us.

Comment: @jcalz what happened is that I just created the constructor but didn't do anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you have tried using a constructor, but maybe you didn't do it right as well.

Here is one way to solve your problem. First an interface is created to unify the user data needed to construct a `User` object.

```
export interface UserData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  status: string;
  role: number;
}
```

Then in the `User` class definition a field of type `UserData` is declared where the user data will be kept.

```
export class User {
  data: UserData;

  constructor(userData: UserData) {
    this.data = userData;
  }

  isAdmin(): boolean {
    return this.data.role === ADMIN;
  }

  // + all other method declarations
}
```

If you don't want to store your user data into a field of type `UserData`, you can just use the interface in the constructor, like this:

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  status: string;
  role: number;

  constructor(userData: UserData) {
    this.id = userData.id;
    this.name = userData.name;
    // etc.
  }

  isAdmin(): boolean {
    return this.role === ADMIN;
  }
}
```

Then you can instantiate objects from the `User` class by using the `new` keyword and the constructor, which takes an `UserData` object as a parameter.

```
export const USERS: User[] = [
  new User({
    id: 301,
    name: "Shirlee Zboncak",
    email: "kenyatta_jerde@erdman.ca",
    phone: "044 93 1342 0977",
    status: "inactive",
    role: 3
  })
];
```

Now you can create `User` objects without specifying the method definitions.

Comment: This looks like a very cool approach. I will use it and I will let you know if it worked for me.

Comment: Added an alternative class definition if you want to keep your existing class declaration field structure.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering how to do that. I tried the way you did it and worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a constructor to the class and just map the array:

```
constructor(id,name,email,phone,status,role) {
    this.id = id;
    //...etc
}
```

then

```
export const USERS: User[] = [{...array values}].map(u=>new User(...u))
```